# UITableViewController Refresh control is nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa

I have a UITableViewController in my project and set the "Refreshing" to enabled in Storyboard. However, the outlet of that is nil.

Using it like this

```
self.refreshControl
```

Even if I make I custom outlet from the storyboard to the viewcontrolelr it is nil. 
It works for other table views in my project, just not for this.

Is there anything quick I probably have missed?

Comment: The default value of this property is nil. You need to instantiate and assign a  UIRefreshControl to self.refreshControl before it exists.

Comment: But I don't need to this in other view controllers? I just set it enabled in the storyboard and it works out of the box. That's how it is supposed to do when using UiTableviewController. But it just does not in this particular case, which is strange and I think I might have missed something

Answer (score 10):

Select your TableViewController in the storyboard and enable refreshing. As depicted in the attached image. I hope this would help.

[image: Storyboard attribute inspector image]

Comment: Important: Make sure you select the UITableViewController! Not the "Table View". I just spent half an hour trying to find a solution, only to find out I was selecting the table view.

Answer (score 7):

you created via storyboard fine. try once remove from storyboard and add it again.

then initiate that in your `viewDidLoad` Method

like  `self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()`

or you can create programatically it will be easy.

create one global Property

```
var refreshControl : UIRefreshControl?
```

in viewDidLoad Add

```
self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

if let refreshControl = self.refreshControl{
   refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(viewCtrl.refresh(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
   self.Tableview.addSubview(refreshControl)
}
```

This will fix your problem.

Comment: yes thought about that. but then I have to do the activity indicator by myself too. I just want to know why it is not working... but thanks, I think I'll do it this way

Comment: activity indicator also can be done in the same way programatically.

Answer (score -1):

```
self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refreshTableView(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Don't forget -> *tableView.addSubView(refreshControl!)*